# Use DISTINCT in COALESCE to remove duplicate value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to count category and subcategory and show in one column in SQL. Here is the first table:

| Category | SubCate | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bird | parrot | 5 |
| Bird | pigeon | 10 |
| Animal | lion | 2 |
| Animal | tiger | 5 |
| Human |  | 7 |

Only the Human Category has no SubCate.

When I use COALESCE function I have this output:

| NEW | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Bird | 15 |
| parrot | 5 |
| piegon | 10 |
| Animal | 7 |
| lion | 2 |
| tiger | 5 |
| Human | 7 |
| Human | 7 |

This is COALESCE query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SubCategory, Category) AS ALL_CATEGORY, SUM(VALUE) AS VALUE
    FROM TEMP_TEST
    GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (Category), (SubCategory, Category)) 
    ORDER BY Category, SubCategory
```

I try to use distinct to remove the duplicate Human record, it has remove but it changes the order very messy. I just want to remove the duplicate Human record, the order must be same as Output table.

Comment: You need to use the coalesce expression everywhere I e. Group by and order by

Comment: Is this really the intended result? Why has tiger the value 5 and not 3, why has animal the value 7 and not 5?...

Comment: Animal value is the sum value of both lion and tiger. Bird value is the sum of parrot and pigeon.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the `SubCategory` value for Human is `NULL`, rather than the empty string. An empty string would be retained by the `COALESCE()` function.

You can replace the null value with an empty string using `ISNULL()` in a subselect.

```
SELECT COALESCE(SubCategory, Category) AS ALL_CATEGORY, SUM(VALUE) AS VALUE
FROM (
    SELECT Category, ISNULL(SubCategory, '') AS SubCategory, Value
    FROM TEMP_TEST
) T
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (Category), (SubCategory, Category)) 
ORDER BY Category, SubCategory
```

An alternative may be to use a `CASE` expression with the `GROUPING()` function in place of the `COALESCE()`.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN GROUPING(SubCategory) = 0 THEN SubCategory ELSE Category END AS ALL_CATEGORY,
    SUM(VALUE) AS VALUE
FROM TEMP_TEST
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (Category), (SubCategory, Category)) 
ORDER BY Category, GROUPING(SubCategory) DESC, SubCategory
```

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/J6ixpTfS) for a demo of both.